# can't use interface which extends another interface as parameter to method

Tags: typescript, extends

I have 3 interfaces :

```
interface IA {
   field1: string
}

interface IB extends A {
   field2: number
}

interface IC {
   test: string;
   myInput: IA
}
```

and a function :

```
test(params: IC) {
   ...
}
```

I'd like my method to be able to receive in `myInput` entry interface `IB`, but, i can only pass interface `IA`, even though `IB` is derived from it.

The error i receive :

```
error TS2322: Type '{ test: string; myInput: IA }' is not assignable to type 'IA'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'test' does not exist in type 'IA'.
```

I tried using something like this to define `myInput` : 
`T<T extends IA>` but it doesn't compile.

Comment: That's not what's happening here. The error suggests you're trying to assign an object of `IC` to `IA` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-c2jojg), everything seems to work.
Open console, to see result.

Comment: that doesn't solve this issue since you can't receive the other object